# Array con inputs en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando crear una tabla con un array de productos, el problema que tengo es que los inputs cogen el valor de cualquier input con el mismo "name".
Cuando intento eliminar alguno de los productos me elimina siempre el ultimo.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gto9bw?file=src/App.js

```
const [producto, setProducto] = useState({
codigo: '',
nombre: '',
descripcion: '',
precio: '',
cantidad: '',
estado: '',


});

  const [productos, setProductos] = useState([]);

  const addProducto = () => {
    setProductos([...productos, producto]);
  };

  const removeProducto = (e, index) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const list = [...productos];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setProductos(list);
  };

  const handleInputChangeProducto = (e, index) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...productos];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setProductos(list);
  };
```

El return con la tabla de los productos, tiene un botón para añadir el producto

```
return (
<div>
  <table className="table-size" style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
      </tr>
      {productos.map((producto, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>
            <input
              name="nombre"
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChangeProducto(e, index)}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              name="descripcion"
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChangeProducto(e, index)}
            />
          </td>
          <td onClick={(e) => removeProducto(e, index)}>
            <Button>Borrar Producto {index}</Button>
            
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </thead>
  </table>
  <br />

  <button onClick={addProducto}>Crear Producto</button>
</div>
```

He intentado separar la parte del "tr" en un componente separado pero tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que estás utilizando los índices de una array como `keys` y react se hace un lío adivinando qué tiene que renderizar y qué no.

Imagina que eliminas el elemento cero de tu array y tienes más elementos, pues react no se va a enterar, porque la `key=0` sigue existiendo, solo que con otro valor. Cómo sigue existiendo, pues no lo renderiza de nuevo y por tanto, no actualiza tu interfaz. De ahí el comportamiento impredecible que tienes en tu código:

De la [documentación de react](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:%7E:text=No%20recomendamos%20usar%20%C3%ADndices%20para%20keys%20si%20el%20orden%20de%20los%20%C3%ADtems%20puede%20cambiar.%20Esto%20puede%20impactar%20negativamente%20el%20rendimiento%20y%20puede%20causar%20problemas%20con%20el%20estado%20del%20componente.):

> No recomendamos usar índices para keys si el orden de los ítems puede cambiar. Esto puede impactar negativamente el rendimiento y puede causar problemas con el estado del componente.

Te recomiendo leer en la documentación todo sobre las keys, ya que son de vital importancia para un renderizado correcto. Las keys de cada producto debe ser única y predecible durante los diferentes ciclos. No puede ser que en un ciclo la key 0 le corresponda a un producto y en el otro ciclo la key 1 le corresponda a otro.

En cuanto a tu código, te recomiendo migrar a utilizar `ids` únicos para cada producto, lo cuál tiene mucho más sentido y se asemeja más a lo que encontrarás en una aplicación real. Nota también que no hay razón para utilizar un `useState` con `producto`, al menos no en el código que expones, ya que nunca cambias el estado:

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function App() {
  const producto = {
    id: '',
    codigo: '',
    nombre: '',
    descripcion: '',
    precio: '',
    cantidad: '',
    estado: '',
  };

  const id = useRef(0);
  const [productos, setProductos] = useState([]);

  const addProducto = () => {
    producto.id = ++id.current;
    setProductos([...productos, producto]);
  };

  const removeProducto = (e, id) => {
    setProductos(productos.filter((p) => p.id != id));
  };

  const handleInputChangeProducto = (e, id) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setProductos(
      productos.map((p) => (p.id == id ? { ...p, [name]:value } : p))
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table-size" style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
          </tr>
          {productos.map((producto, index) => (
              <tr key={producto.id}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    name="nombre"
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChangeProducto(e, producto.id)}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input
                    name="descripcion"
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChangeProducto(e, producto.id)}
                  />
                </td>
                <td onClick={(e) => removeProducto(e, producto.id)}>
                  <button>Borrar Producto {index}</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </thead>
      </table>
      <br />

      <button onClick={addProducto}>Crear Producto</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Alternativamente te dejo el enlace de [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wb187q?file=src/App.js).